# How to treat Firefox tabs as windows?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a way to treat Firefox tabs as windows like on Edge? After using edge for a bit I found that I rely on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a lot and merging my browser tabs with the rest of the windows was a far better experience (of course without actually creating a bunch of windows)

Comment: Unclear: Ctrl+Tab works to switch to the next tab the same way in Firefox and Edge. So what are you doing?

Comment: I meant  Alt + Tab (which is meant to switch between open windows), sorry for the typo @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

Such an option exists inside Firefox when it has the focus.
It is possible to configure
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
to put up an identical display to that of Windows
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

- Click the hamburger menu icon on top right and select "Options"
- In the General section, scroll down to "Tabs"
- Click to select
  "Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order".

Now when Firefox is in front, clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
will display all the tabs as windows.

[image]

For more information with screenshots see the article
[Turn On Alt+Tab Like View for Firefox Tabs To Switch Between Tabs](https://www.techwareguide.com/how-to-turn-on-alt-tab-view-for-firefox-tabs/).

Comment: I am not sure If you've used edge recently but theirs merges the tabs to actual application windows. like you don't need to put mozilla in front to swicth between tabs..when you do `Alt` + `Tab` you see all your tabs layedout with all the other open windows but when in edge they are still contained as tabs. It might be only exclusive to edge but It was a cool touch and I wondered if similar thing existed in mozilla

Comment: I believe this is the closest that's possible to get to it. I don't know of an identical feature or add-on.